# Downloading photos from Facebook group pages

Tags: photos, facebook

I'm trying to set up an easy way for folks to share photos for a reunion, then use those photos in a slideshow.

Since everybody is on facebook, that would be the preferred method.

There is already a facebook group in place for the reunion.

When folks start adding photos, what would be the best way to download those photos without relying on outside 3rd-party web services?

I tried a few browser plugins/extensions, but they were a few years old and didn't work (I assume because of the changes facebook has gone through since the plugins were last updated).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Facebook questions belong on webapps.se

Answer (score 0):

I list below several solutions which might help you in downloading group photos.
Not having a Facebook group I cannot test them, so you will have to check which one
works well for your group.

Website: [PicknZip](http://www.picknzip.com/)
Applications: [Fotobounce](http://fotobounce.com/download/), [PhotoGrabber](http://photograbber.org/), [fbDownloader](http://fbdownloader.com/)
Android: [PicDownloader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.giannz.photodownloader&hl=en)
iPhone: [PhotoJacker](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photojacker/id573293275?ls=1&mt=8)
Browser: Save-images extensions exist for all major browsers.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, all those applications only seem to be able to download photos from albums in a personal profile, not photos/albums from group pages.

Comment: They were all advertised as being able to use groups, which is why I listed them. Maybe you could raise the question with the developers or forums for these projects that have such.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook no more support this function.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Once there was "photos" object, now they removed it (maybe privacy issue???)

If they dont take it back it will be "harder" to download photos, since you cant do any automatic task without api access.

When they wil take back this api you can use this method to retrieve a json object with photo links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869595/retrieve-photos-from-a-facebook-group-using-the-graphapi